# Format a printed char array in C - quotations marks and right aligment

Tags: c

I'm new on C and I'm having troubles trying to format a String.

The format that I use to print is this:

```
cp = "42947295";
printf("String value: \"%-10s\"  <-->  Unsigned long value: %10lu\n", cp, dwAtoDW(cp));

cp = "123456789";
printf("String value: \"%-10s\"  <-->  Unsigned long value: %10lu\n", cp, dwAtoDW(cp));

cp = "100000";
printf("String value: \"%-10s\"  <-->  Unsigned long value: %10lu\n", cp, dwAtoDW(cp));

unsigned long dwAtoDW(char* cpPtr) {
    number = 0;
    while (*cpPtr) {
        if (*cpPtr >= '0' && *cpPtr <= '9') {
            number *= 10;
            number += *cpPtr - '0';
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    *cpPtr++;
    }
    return number;
}
```

And I have the following output:

```
String value: "4294967295"    Unsigned long value: 4294967295
String value: " 123456789"    Unsigned long value:  123456789
String value: "    100000"    Unsigned long value:     100000
```

As you can see, when printing values that are less that 10 characters long, it prints spaces between the two quotations marks. What I want is to maintain the right alignment, with the quotation marks arround the whole number, like this:

```
String value: "4294967295"    Unsigned long value: 4294967295
String value:  "123456789"    Unsigned long value:  123456789
String value:     "100000"    Unsigned long value:     100000
```

Is there a way to do that with printf format codes?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt this is possible as the `"`s are not part of the value being printed. Something hacky would be to make `dwAtoDW` resilient to encountering `"`s (ignore them), and then change the `cp` assignment to `cp = "\"100000\"";`

Comment: Yeah, it should work that way, but the problem is that those `cp` values can't be modified at all (forgot to mention that).

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this using one line of `printf`. However, you can use `sprintf` first to put the quotes around the text, and then use `printf` to align the output.

```
char buffer[20];
sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\"", tp);
printf("String value: %-12s  <-->  Unsigned long value: %10lu\n", buffer, dwAtoDW(cp));
```

Comment: Well, in the assignment work didn't mention anything about using sprintf, so I guess I'm going to use that.

Thanks a lot!